# How to calculate the size of a given number of rectangles that cover a larger area

Tags: math

I am working a project where we have a set area (1000 x 1300) area.
I need the mathematical equation that I can enter a integer and have it broken into equal shapes.

So if I need to break up this area up into 170 "bricks" the equation should tell me that each brick needs to be 100px x 60 px  (this is just example)

Comment: "bricks"..."hitting a wall"... :D

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is called tesselation; as always [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) has a nice article about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it simple (language agnostic):

```
overallHeight = 1300;
overallWidth = 1000;

numberOfBricks = 170;
squareRootOfBrickCount = sqrt(numberOfBricks);

brickHeight = int(overallHeight/squareRootOfBrickCount);
brickWidth = int(overallWidth/squareRootOfBrickCount);
```

For the right-most and bottom-most bricks you'll have to add in any extra pixels that were left out due to `int` operation during calculation:

```
extraHeight = overallHeight - (int(squareRootOfBrickCount) * brickHeight);
extraWidth = overallWidth - (int(squareRootOfBrickCount) * brickWidth);
```